# How to create a Cassandra node Cluster in Windows7 pcs?

Tags: cassandra

Problem while Creating cluster using cassandra:-

I follow the below steps for creating a Cassandra cluster:-
    1.Installed cassandra in 3 Windows-7 PCs.
    PC IPAddress-127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3

```
2.Modified the cassandra.yaml file as below.
  cluster_name: 'MyCluster'
  num_tokens: 256
  seed_provider:  - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
  listen_address: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3
  rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

3.start the Cassandra in all the above 3 PCs.

but I am not getting more than 1 Node in Node tool. I can see only one node.  

I have installed  datastax-community-64bit_2.0.3

So, Please help me to solve this problem. I need to create Cassandra cluster.
Thanks in Adavance,
Satya
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have follow all the steps for creating cluster,but you have to define firewall inbound rule for allowing the port.(by default these ports are not allowed by firewall).So after modifying the "cassandra.yaml" file,you have to set the port used in cassandra and datastax in your firewall,then start the cassandra service.
    For adding port in firewall:
    go to control panel->windows firewall->advanced setting->Inbound Rules->new Rule->select port and add all the ports require for the cassandra/datastax. google the require ports for cassandra/datastax.

Comment: You have to modify the listen address as well.Use the ip address of your system as the listen address.(don't use all the ip address of your cluster).e.g in your 1st node's cassandra.yaml file it should be listen_address: 127.0.0.1 and in 2nd node listen_address: 127.0.0.2 and 3rd listen_address: 127.0.0.3.

Comment: Thanks subhra. Its working fine for me. I have changed the listen_address in the config file and added the ports(7000, 7001, 9160, 7199, 9042, 8888, 50031, 61620, 8012, 9290, 50030, 50060, 61621, 22, 8983) to the firewall inbound rules.

Answer (score 1):

The 127.x.x.x IP addresses you are using are all loopback device addresses. Traffic sent to those addresses never leaves your localhost. If you want the three hosts to discover each other you need to use IPs from some private IP address range. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) for an overview. As your Windows workstations are networked, the IP number to use should be obvious from running `ipconfig` on the command line on each of the three workstations. Look for the output entry `IPv4-Adress`.

Comment: @satya Could you update your question with your current config?

Comment: Hi Ralf,I have added my System IP address[10.0.0.132 ...so on].I was just given (127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3) for example purpose.